# Populate More of the Cloudflare Cache Servers Each Time the Cache Expires

Tags: caching, cloudflare

### Background

I am caching the HTML (in addition to the typical static resources) of some dynamic pages using Cloudflare. The issue I'm experiencing is that the cache is not utilized much of the time, meaning most people are getting slow pages. You can see that with this Cloudflare graph:

[image: Cloudflare Cache Performance]

You can see that only 6.7K requests are served by Cloudflare, whereas 11.5K requests are served by the origin server. There are only a few hundred pages on the site, so there should be ample opportunity for the cache to be used.

### Theory

My theory is that Cloudflare has hundreds of servers, and it only caches on each of those servers when a request passes through that particular server. Say there are 100 Cloudflare servers. That means if somebody visits the site, their response will only be cached on 1 server and the 99 others will need to have somebody visit the site through them in order for them to have their cache populated.

### Question

My question is: **is there some way to populate all the Cloudflare servers with the same cached response any time a page is cached with any of the Cloudflare servers?**

The idea is that this would improve cache performance such that more people would be served a cached version of the page rather than having to wait for the uncached version of the page to be fetched.

Comment: https://blog.cloudflare.com/tiered-cache-smart-topology/

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for the tip! I've enabled Argo (which includes tiered caching), so I'll see how it impacts the metrics in a few days.

Comment: @MarkB The metrics definitely improved (from 37% of page requests served by Cloudflare to 60% of page requests served by Cloudflare). I have some other tricks to try, but this is a great first step and I consider this to be the answer to my question. If you write it up in answer form, I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Argo/Tiered Caching definitely improved things (thanks, [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13070/mark-b)!), they didn't get me entirely where I wanted to be.

I found that lots of visitors were being sent to the site with unique combinations of query strings (e.g., "utm_source=google" and "gclid=ljslj3j33432").

To get around that, I created a rewrite rule that ignores those query strings when other special query strings aren't present. This was possible thanks to a new feature called transform rules: https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-transform-rules-with-url-rewriting-at-the-edge/

On top of that, I also extended both the edge cache duration (s-maxage) and stale revalidation period (stale-while-revalidate).

Combining all those techniques, I was able to get to approximately 97% of first visits being served from the Cloudflare cache.